# Updating Ubuntu touch on nexus 7

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am using ubuntu touch on my nexus 7. I installed the stable release yesterday (18/10/2013), using the command:

```
sudo phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup
```

This successfully installed the latest build on my nexus 7.

Now when I type the following code in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Why is this so? I am able to update using the System Settings->Updates. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

adb shell touch /userdata/.writable_image

adb reboot

I saw in on this page:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~popey/+junk/phablet-flash-wrapper/view/head:/post-flash.sh